# Flex lexer start condition not being recognized

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, lexer

I have a scanner that maintains two exclusive states (WORD and DEFN)

```
%option noyywrap
%s WORD
%s DEFN
%%

%{
    BEGIN(WORD);
%}

<WORD>{
"|"          { BEGIN(DEFN); return WS_PIPE; }
}

<DEFN>{
[^;]+        { printf("ds: %s\n", yytext); return WD_STRING; }
";"          { return WD_SEMICOLON; }
}

\n|.         { printf("U: %s\n", yytext); }

%%
```

But with the simple input "| some text;", when the pipe is parsed the state is not being changed, so the parsing of "some text;" fails.

Comment: You don't need to use start states in this grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is certainly being changed to `DEFN` when a `|` is encountered in state `WORD`. However, the next time `yylex` is called (to get the token following the pipe), the state is reset to `WORD` by the block

```
%{
    BEGIN(WORD);
%}
```

From the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Rules-Section.html) (emphasis added):

> In the rules section, any indented or %{ %} enclosed text appearing before the first rule may be used to declare variables which are local to the scanning routine and (after the declarations) **code which is to be executed whenever the scanning routine is entered**.

You're really better off using the `INITIAL` start condition to represent the, well, initial start condition.

Comment: That was *exactly* the problem - thank you! Is there any way to set the initial state to something other that "INITIAL"?

Comment: @AndrewS: not as far as I know, which is why it makes sense to use INITIAL as the initial state. There is nothing else special about `INITIAL`, so there is no reason not to use it that way.

Comment: @AndrewS.: actually there is a way, but its ugly. You add a single `<INITIAL>` rule which matches `.|\n`, whose action is to change the start condition, and then uses `yyless(1)` to put the matched character back into the stream. But why bother? Just use `INITIAL` as the initial start condition. Aside from anything else, doing so makes your tables smaller.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. Have moved everything in the <WORD> rule to the INITIAL rule and all is well now - thank you for the help.

Comment: You can also use `BEGIN(WORD);` in a function you define in the third section of your .l file (after the final `%%` you have) which you call before calling yyparse or yylex.

Comment: There is ONE sort-of-ok reason not to want to use `INITIAL` as the -- um -- initial condition: `INITIAL` is inclusive of rules declared without a scan condition and you may not want that. Yes, you can get around the problem by being explicit about which conditions all your rules apply to, but that's more work and potentially a maintenance trap.

Comment: @ian: yeah, I've been there. But since flex lets you put a bunch of rules inside a start condition block, it"s actually not really that annoying to be explicit. The other case is where some start conditions are inclusive, but the initial state is not the base case. However, inclusive start conditions also often turn out to be a maintenance trap. Anyway, this particular question is neither of these cases.